# Can I reuse explicit wait from base class with Selenium WebDriver and PHPUnit?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phpunit, wait, explicit

Is there a way to reuse explicit wait from base class?

My Base Class scenario:

```
public class BaseClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase 
{
    public function baseClassTest()
    {
        $driverWait = new WebDriverWait($this->webDriver, 80);
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

My Test class scenario:

```
public class ClassTest extends BaseClassTest
{
    public function testClass()
    {
       $baseTest = parent::baseClassTest();
       $driverWait->until(expectedCondition....);
       return $baseTest 
    }
}
```

This is showing compile time error in My Test class, saying: undefined variable 'driverWait'. 
Where am I going wrong? please help!

Comment: I think you need to declare  'WebDriverWait $driverWait = new WebDriverWait($this->webDriver, 80);'

Comment: Thank you Sudeepthi but i have already did it in my baseClassTest() function